# Create a file programmatically

Tags: files

I am working on a cron job that is creating a backup file.  I want to move the file to the private file directory but I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.  The cron job creates a file in a folder called /temp in the root of my site.  I've been trying to use `file_save_upload` to move the file, but this isn't working

```
$gzip_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/temp/myfile.gz';
$private_file = 'private://myfolder/myfile.gz';
$drupal_file = file_save_upload($gzip_file,array(),$private_file,FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

I am not getting an error and $drupal_file equals false.  The private folder exists and I can write to it with PHP.  Is file_save_upload the wrong function?  What do I need to do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's an 'unmanaged' file, i.e one that doesn't have a database entry, you can use either

1. [`file_unmanaged_move`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_move/7) or
2. [`file_unmanaged_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_save_data/7)

Comment: What of I want to make it a managed file?

Comment: For managed files you can use [`file_save_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7)

Comment: Both are global functions... I can't believe there are no OO ways with services to do this. Any ideas?